# Querystring value in sqldatasourse

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5, webforms, sqldatasource

I have the following which works fine:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="test_library_newsletter_Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div  style="font-family:Arial;">
        <asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
        datasourceid="CustomersSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="false"
        emptydatatext="No data available." 
        allowpaging="true" 
        runat="server"
        ShowHeader="True"
        GridLines="None"
        CellPadding="10">

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date"
            DataField="date"
            dataformatstring="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />

            <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Subject"
            DataTextField="subject"
            DataNavigateUrlFields="id"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://intranet/Default2.aspx?id={0}" />
        </Columns>

        <pagersettings mode="Numeric"
        position="Bottom"           
        pagebuttoncount="10"/>

            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />


        </asp:gridview>

        <asp:sqldatasource id="CustomersSource"
        selectcommand="select id, subject, date from table order by id desc"
        connectionstring="connection string here" 
        runat="server"/>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I want to use a querystring value in the sql statement.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need something like this

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ID" runat="server" ConnectionString="connectionString"
    ProviderName="providerName"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName], [UnitPrice] FROM [Products] WHERE     ([CategoryID] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Type="Int32" 
            Name="CategoryID" 
            QueryStringField="CategoryID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Read full post at 
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150717/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030106-1.aspx

Hope it helps.